# Rails db:seed how to bypass validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, migrate, seeding

Error Message:

```
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Status : Event is Locked
```

I stored a bunch of test data in seeds.rb that I am having trouble seeding w/ db:seed.

Prediction structure

```
  {user_id: 2, event_id: 3, fighter_guess: "Jessica Andrade", method_guess: "Decision"},
  {user_id: 2, event_id: 3, fighter_guess: "Claudio Puelles", method_guess: "Submission"},
  {user_id: 2, event_id: 2, fighter_guess: "Vicente Luque", method_guess: "Decision"},
  {user_id: 2, event_id: 2, fighter_guess: "Caio Borralho", method_guess: "TKO/KO"},
  {user_id: 2, event_id: 1, fighter_guess: "Korean Zombie", method_guess: "TKO/KO"},
  {user_id: 2, event_id: 1, fighter_guess: "Petr Yan", method_guess: "Decision"},
  {user_id: 2, event_id: 4, fighter_guess: "Rob Font", method_guess: "Submission"},
  {user_id: 2, event_id: 5, fighter_guess: "Charles Oliveira", method_guess: "Decision"},
  {user_id: 2, event_id: 5, fighter_guess: "Rose Namajunas", method_guess: "Submission"},
  {user_id: 2, event_id: 6, fighter_guess: "Aleksandar Rakic", method_guess: "Decision"},
  ...
```

I have a validation for the Prediction model that checks for the status of the event_id in question to be "Upcoming", before allowing the prediction to be made. So when I run db:seed, it fails the validation because some of the events are not "Upcoming".

Event structure

```
  {event_name: "UFC FN: LEMOS x ANDRADE", f1: "Amanda Lemos", f2: "Jessica Andrade", f3: "Clay Guida", f4: "Claudio Puelles", status: "Concluded", date: "Sat, Apr 23"},
  {event_name: "UFC FN: FONT x VERA", f1: "Rob Font", f2: "Marlon Vera", f3: "Andrei Arlovski", f4: "Jake Collier", status: "Concluded", date: "Sat, Apr 30"},
  {event_name: "UFC 274", f1: "Charles Oliveira", f2: "Justin Gaethje", f3: "Rose Namajunas", f4: "Carla Esparza", status: "Upcoming", date: "Sat, May 7"},
```

Prediction.rb

```
class Prediction < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :event
    belongs_to :user

    validate :prediction_no_longer_allowed



    def prediction_no_longer_allowed
        if self.event.concluded? || self.event.in_progress?
            errors.add(:status, ": Event is Locked")
        end
    end
end
```

Event.rb

```
...
    def concluded?
        self.status == "Concluded"
    end

    def in_progress?
        self.status == "In Progress"
    end
```

For my scenario of wanting to share the app with others to test functionality, it would save a lot of time if I could bypass validations for seeding purposes.

I am seeding data in order of:
User --> Event --> Prediction

Comment: It's not good idea to hardcode ids in DB

Comment: `unknown attribute 'validate'` -- where did you use this `validate`? That's the problem

Comment: I posted the wrong error message from when I was trying to find a solution. Fixed it mb.

Comment: So you need to create records in DB with these attributes and skip validations?

Comment: Yeah, that's the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`insert_all`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-insert_all) method

> Inserts multiple records into the database in a single SQL INSERT statement. It does not instantiate any models nor does it trigger Active Record callbacks or validations. Though passed values go through Active Record's type casting and serialization.

```
Prediction.insert_all([
  {user_id: 2, event_id: 3, fighter_guess: "Jessica Andrade", method_guess: "Decision"},
  {user_id: 2, event_id: 3, fighter_guess: "Claudio Puelles", method_guess: "Submission"},
  {user_id: 2, event_id: 2, fighter_guess: "Vicente Luque", method_guess: "Decision"},
  {user_id: 2, event_id: 2, fighter_guess: "Caio Borralho", method_guess: "TKO/KO"},
  {user_id: 2, event_id: 1, fighter_guess: "Korean Zombie", method_guess: "TKO/KO"},
  {user_id: 2, event_id: 1, fighter_guess: "Petr Yan", method_guess: "Decision"},
  {user_id: 2, event_id: 4, fighter_guess: "Rob Font", method_guess: "Submission"},
  {user_id: 2, event_id: 5, fighter_guess: "Charles Oliveira", method_guess: "Decision"},
  {user_id: 2, event_id: 5, fighter_guess: "Rose Namajunas", method_guess: "Submission"},
  {user_id: 2, event_id: 6, fighter_guess: "Aleksandar Rakic", method_guess: "Decision"},
])
```

May be it's better to create first specific events and users. And then call `user_id: my_super_user.id, event_id: my_super_event.id` etc.